# MVC ASP.NET Get value from dictionary of controller

Tags: asp.net, dictionary, model-view-controller

I have a dictionary in the Controller file, where everytime someone pressed a button it goes to the ActionResult, and will be incremented into the dictionary by the id. But how do I access this dictionary from my model files?

Edited:
Changed approach
my model has StringBuilder that contains html script. there's a "like" link where everytime it is pressed it should update the value of likes right below. By doing this, I'm using dictionary to store the id of the post, and the number of likes. Should I use js ajax to make it real-time?

```
build.Append("<a href='ControllerName/Method?id=" + id + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up' title='Like'></span></a>");
build.Append(GetValue(Int32.Parse(id)) + "likes");
```

Comment: Please add example code.

Comment: What logic are you writing in a model that requires an object in the controller? If it is the button press', it should be in the controller; not in the model